# What's the difference between germ line and germ cells?

Tags: genetics

I'm currently reading some introductory chapters about genetics (in Campbell's book, chapter 13) and I realized that I don't really understand what is the difference between the *germ line* and the *germ cells*.

From what I read so far, I understand that *germ cells* are specialized cells from which gametes are produced, and I suppose that the *germ line* is the "set" of all germ cells + gametes, but for some reason I couldn't find a good definition of what the germ line is and I was not satisfied with what I found in books and on the internet (because it was not as clear as I thought it could be)...

So, even if I'm ashamed to ask... Could someone explain to me the difference between those two concepts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Germ cells are the cells of germline. Germline is a lineage of germ cells from germline stem cells to gametes. Cells that do not belong to germline are called somatic cells.

Comment: ...and **somatic cells** form the **soma** (which should maybe be called *somatic line* instead for clarity). +1